# How to egrep multiple phrases that contain a variable

Tags: shell, grep

```
for svc in a b c d
 do
 service_status=$(service xy-mp-$svc status)
 if echo $service_status | egrep -i 'xy-mp-"$svc" dead but pid file exists|xy-mp-"$svc" is   stopped' &> /dev/null
 then
      service xy-mp-$svc restart
 fi             
 done
```

With "`$svc`",the variable substitution isn't taking place in the egrep.Does anyone have ideas on how I could do the variable substitution in this example?

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, only double quotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: [if echo $service_status | egrep -i "xy-mp-"$svc dead but pid file exists"|"xy-mp-$svc is stopped" &> /dev/null
 then
      service xy-mp-$svc restart
 fi]The above segment doesn't seem to work,but this seems to work:[if echo $service_status | egrep -i "xy-mp-$svc is stopped" &> /dev/null
 then
      service xy-mp-$svc restart
 fi ]

Comment: @Barmar,could you comment on this?I'm still unable to egrep for multiple phrases.Pls refer to this fpaste link

Comment: http://fpaste.org/130237/62193114/

Comment: The format to `grep` for alternatives is `grep "alt1\|alt2\|alt3" input`. The `or` in `grep` `alt1 or alt2 or alt3` is the pipe `|`. **Note:** within double-quotes you must escape the pipe with `\\` to prevent it from being interpreted literally as a pipe by the shell **and** you must use double-quotes to enclose your alternatives.